# Aligning flex items to the flex-end

Tags: css, flexbox

Hei,

I'm creating grid layout and when trying to align items on flex-end or start, height/width becomes zero. 
What I'm wondering is, is it possible to align items in flex container to the top/bottom/center WITHOUT specifying height/width? In my case I didn't specify any height and it doesn't work. If I specify it, it works. Line that doesn't work is commented in first example.

Here is code:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background: silver; 
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  //align-items: flex-start; 
}

.flex-item {
  background: blue; 
  flex: 1 0 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.flex-container2 {
  display: flex;
  background: silver; 
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: flex-end; 
}

.flex-item2 {
  background: blue; 
  height: 50px;
  flex: 1 0 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="flex-container2">
  <div class="flex-item2"></div>
  <div class="flex-item2"></div>
  <div class="flex-item2"></div>
  <div class="flex-item2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I clarified everything, there's an answer below. I just wanted empty containers aligned on top/bottom of parent container with flex-end or flex-start WITHOUT specifying height or width. I forgot about content although..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the default value for align-items is `stretch`, hence they fill their parents height, and you change it to `flex-start`/`flex-end`, the row flex items becomes 0 in height, and will need content (or a height/min-height) for you to actually see them.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background: silver; 
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: flex-start; 
}

.flex-item {
  background: blue;
  min-height: 20px;
  flex: 1 0 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.flex-container2 {
  display: flex;
  background: silver; 
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: flex-end; 
}

.flex-item2 {
  background: blue; 
  height: 50px;
  flex: 1 0 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">They need content or a height/min-height</div>
  <div class="flex-item">They need content or a height/min-height</div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="flex-container2">
  <div class="flex-item2"></div>
  <div class="flex-item2"></div>
  <div class="flex-item2"></div>
  <div class="flex-item2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Totally forgot about content. I was playing just with empty containers and I knew I had it working last time but now it just didn't want to play it my way. I used the option with height or width but I wanted them to grow without specifying height or width..Thanks!